# Selenium IDE_I need to select the bcc hyper link using selenium ide and type the valid email id

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-ide

I need to select the BCC Hyper Link in the Compose window of the Gmail and then type the mail address using selenium ide?
Can someone please give me some examples for this?

Using Xpath or CSS selector/DOM

Comment: Please provide the HTML of the page around the element you need to automate as well as showing what you have tried so far in selenium to do this

Comment: HTML Code Of my project--> <table class="hupa-msg-headers" style="width: 100%;">
<colgroup>
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<td class="label">
<div class="hupa-hyperlink">
<a class="gwt-Anchor" href="javascript:;">Bcc:</a>
</div>
</td>
<td class="value">
</tr>
<tr>
<tr>
</tbody>
</table>

Answer (score 0):

Have tried this:

```
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>//span[text()='Bcc']</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>name=bcc</td>
    <td>abc@abc.com</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Can u please explain elaborately 
How can i get the xpath from  above  HTML code

Comment: I use firebug to examine the dom. I then take a look at auto-generated xpath and edit it to something that seem less hard coded to me. 
So I got an original value of //*[@id=":nc"] but I realized that ID is going to be dynamic so it doesn't do what I need. So I look that it's a span element that has defined text that I would like.

Comment: To use selenium well you should check out the many xpath tutorials available to gain more power: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_nodes.asp